# Visualization of categorical data by percentage and group

Tags: ggplot2, percentage, categorical-data, group

I am trying to visualize two categorical data with ggplot by group and percentage. In other words, I would like that the percentage is based by group, not the whole data.

Here is a sample:

```
# Data
c <- c("Impossible", "Easy", "Impossible", "Difficult", "Impossible", "Difficult", "Easy", "Easy",
"Easy", "Difficult")
d <- c("F", "F", "V", "V", "F", "F", "V", "F", "V", "F")
e <- data.frame(c,d)

# Visualization
t <- e %>%
  group_by(d) %>%
  ggplot(DataT, mapping = aes(c)) +                            
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..), fill = d), position="dodge2") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)
t
```

[Visualization of percentage for each lvl c by lvl d](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CAna.png)

The percentage of each level is based on the whole data, not per group. In instance, F has a total percentage of 60%, not 100%. How can I get the 100%? Thanks for your help.

C.L.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to do something like this:

```
e %>% 
  group_by(c) %>%
  count(d) %>%
  group_by(d) %>%
  mutate(perc=n/sum(n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=c,y=perc, fill=d)) + geom_col(position = "dodge")
```